# Razor Syntax - using model property inside Url.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to write this using Razor syntax:

```
<div style="background: url(@Url.Content("~/images/@Model.ImageUrl"))">
</div>
```

I am using `@Url.Content("")` and need to use a Model property within the string but I can't figure out the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@` expressions contain normal C# code.
You need to perform ordinary string concatenation:

```
@Url.Content("~/images/" + Model.ImageUrl))
```